# Having problems streaming my firebase realtime database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im receiving a type error when I try to stream my firebase real time database. Here is the MRE of my code. Ive been using other features of the module perfectly but for some reason this error keep appearing when I try to stream my data.

```
from firebase import Firebase
import python_jwt as jwt
from gcloud import storage
from sseclient import SSEClient
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine

config = {
    "apiKey": "*******************************",
  "authDomain": "*********************************",
  "databaseURL": "*********************************",
  "storageBucket": "********************************"

}

pythonfirebase = Firebase(config)
db = pythonfirebase.database()

def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"])  # put
    print(message["path"])  # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"])  # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}

my_stream = db.child("placements").stream(stream_handler)
```

Here is the full traceback

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 593, in start_stream
    self.sse = ClosableSSEClient(self.url, session=self.make_session(), build_headers=self.build_headers)
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 554, in __init__
    super(ClosableSSEClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sseclient.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 558, in _connect
    super(ClosableSSEClient, self)._connect()
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sseclient.py", line 56, in _connect
    self.resp = requester.get(self.url, stream=True, **self.requests_kwargs)
  File "/Users/temitayoadefemi/PycharmProjects/test7/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'build_headers'
```

Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Try it with Firebase admin sdk instead

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)

# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': DATABASE_URL
})

# Get a database reference to our posts
ref = db.reference('messages')

def listener(event):
  print(event.event_type)  # can be 'put' or 'patch'
  print(event.path)  # relative to the reference, it seems
  print(event.data)  # new data at /reference/event.path. None if deleted

  node = str(event.path).split('/')[-2] #you can slice the path according to your requirement
  property = str(event.path).split('/')[-1]
  value = event.data
  if (node=='sala'):
  #do something
    """"""
  elif (node=='ventilacion'):
  #do something
    """"""
  else:
    """"""
#do something else

# Read the data at the posts reference (this is a blocking operation)
# print(ref.get())

db.reference('/').listen(listener)
```